# Performance issue in zooming

Tags: flutter, dart

I created Myapp class and Panner class for zooming, scrolling, panning the image in flutter. I have a problem with Zooming the image

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:zoomexample/Panner.dart';
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            showPerformanceOverlay: true,
            theme: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            ),
            home:
            Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Zoom view",)),body:Center(child: Panner(),))
        );
      }
    } 

 panner class

    import 'dart:typed_data';
    import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    class Panner extends StatefulWidget {

      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() => PannerState();

    }

    class PannerState extends State<Panner> {
      String assets ;
      Uint8List pageData;
      double scrollPosx=0,scrollPosy=0,previousPosx=0,previousPosy=0;
      double scale = 1.0, previousScale = 1.0;
      double originalImageHeight, imageHeight;
      Offset _offset = Offset.zero;
      Offset _previousOffset, _startingFocalPoint;
      ScrollController _verticalController = ScrollController();
      ScrollController _horizontalController = ScrollController();

      _findPosition()
      {    

            _previousOffset=Offset(-scrollPosx,-scrollPosy);
            previousPosx=-scrollPosx;
            previousPosy=-scrollPosy;
        }
      }
      Future _getImage(BuildContext context) async {
        if(pageData == null)
        {
          assets = 'images/squirrel.jpg';
          imageHeight = originalImageHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height; 
          pageData = ((await rootBundle.load(assets)).buffer.asUint8List());
        }
      }
      _onScaleUpdate(ScaleUpdateDetails details) {
        scale = details.scale * previousScale;
        if(scale!=1.0) {
          if (scale < 0.5) {
            scale = 0.5;
          }
          imageHeight = originalImageHeight * scale;
          setState(() {});
          final Offset normalizedOffset = (_startingFocalPoint -
              _previousOffset) / previousScale;
          _offset = details.focalPoint - normalizedOffset * scale;
          _horizontalController.jumpTo(-_offset.dx);
          _verticalController.jumpTo(-_offset.dy);

        }

      }

      _onScaleStart(ScaleStartDetails details) {
        _startingFocalPoint = details.focalPoint;
        previousScale = scale;
        _previousOffset = _offset;
        scrollPosx=_horizontalController.position.pixels;
        scrollPosy=_verticalController.position.pixels;
        if(previousPosx!=scrollPosx || previousPosy!=scrollPosy)
          {
            _findPosition();
          }
    setState(() {});

      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return FutureBuilder(
            future: _getImage(context),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if(pageData==null)
              {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
           return  GestureDetector(
                    onScaleStart: _onScaleStart,
                    onScaleUpdate: _onScaleUpdate,
                    // onScaleEnd: _onScaleEnd,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    controller: _horizontalController,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        controller: _verticalController,
                     child: Align(
                        alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                          child: Image.memory(
                            pageData,
                            height: imageHeight,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                           width: imageWidth,
                          ),
                        )
                    ),
                  )
                  ) ;
            });
      }
    }
```

For zooming the image I use gesture detector.when zooming the image it doesn't work smoothly and multi-finger zooming doesn't respond correctly a few times, when multi-finger zooming doesn't respond at that time console indicates that the application can do too much work on it's main thread.Thanks in advance

Comment: If your log doesn't display any errors it's most likely because you're in debug mode which significantly reduces performance in order to give you debugging features. Try building the release version and see if the problem is still there.

Comment: I build the app in release mode. I still facing the problem in zooming .when I zoom a image sometime it is not respond properly